# How to add condition to compare two array and change value of match array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I want to compare two array in that i want to change value of matching id.

Please refer bellow array's and result.

```
let array1 =[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "value": true
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "value": false
  }
]


let array2 = [
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 4
  }
]
```

I want to use underscore library to compare this arrays and return the compare array value result as like below array

```
result = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "value": true
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "value": true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const array1 =[{"id": 1,"value": false},{"id": 2,"value": false},{"id": 3,"value": true},{"id": 4,"value": false}]
const array2 = [{"id": 1},{"id": 4}]

const result = array1.map(({id, value}) => ({
  id,
  value: value || array2.some(item => item.id === id)
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution by using map

```js
let array1 =[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "value": true
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "value": false
  }
]


let array2 = [
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 4
  }
]

const resultArr = array1.map((item) => {
      if (array2.findIndex((item2) => {return item2.id == item.id}) !== - 1) {
          item.value = true;
      }
      return item; 
  })
  console.log(resultArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
array1.forEach(item => {
    item.value = item.value || array2.some(item2 => item2.id === item.id)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lodash.map` with `lodash.some` to check for object and update the `value`.

```js
let array1 =[ { "id": 1, "value": false }, { "id": 2, "value": false }, { "id": 3, "value": true }, { "id": 4, "value": false } ],
    array2 = [ { "id": 1 }, { "id": 4 } ],
    result = _.map(array1, o => ({...o, value : _.some(array2, ({id}) => id === o.id) || o.value}));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```